# Time not correct Issue

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am using *Google Play Services* in my app to get the current location.

I have also put a check to identify if *Google Play Services* is present or not or it needs to be updated.

When I run this code on a Tablet with Wifi, it works fine.

However when I use 3g, It show me this error "**The date on the device appears to be incorrect. Please check the date on the device.**". I wonder why

The app is inbuild in the device, once the device is switched on, the app will automatically start and 3g or Wifi will be connected.

The code to check for *Google Play Services* is from [isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context))

Any help?